# Simple, low impact motion detection

Tags: stereo-vision

I am interested in using stereo vision that is immune to shadow movement, or specular disturbances.

I'm not interested in high accuracy point clouds, or accurate speed measurement, really just a simple moving blob detection.  It seems to me that this should be doable by using only a couple hundred points in the field of view, limiting calculation requirements.

If two stereo images were thresholded and reduced to a couple hundred black pixels, would the 3D algorithm work on something like an ESP32 at maybe 5 frames per second?

I haven't been able to find any libraries for this, but have found some published papers.

Comment: it's pretty hard to say what you could do on any given microcontroller; especially, considering you seem to be planning to do the stereo image calculation /thresholding elsewhere. Why not do the motion detection on that piece of computational hardware, too?

Comment: I could.  The information I have been reading is that this is about one image per second using about 10 year old processors.  I'm thinking about two approaches, first is to edge detect, then threshold the images, then do stereo.  That may reduce the computational effort to find common features.  The second thought is to decimate the resolution to something like 100x100 pixels.  I did find some libraries on GitHub, but most look like thesis studies, and nothing that's been maintained recently.